# Почему выдача не в том порядке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал вот такой код и не понимаю почему выдача не в том порядке.

```py
one = input().split(' ')
two = input().split(' ')
three = set(one) - set(two)
print(*three)
```

Задание на 1 скриншоте, ошибка на 2 скриншоте. Помогите пожалуйста исправить.

[image: Задание]

[image: Ошибки]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134179/discussion-on-question-by-sd1g------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
c = sorted(set(a)-set(b))
print(*c)
```